# Private messaging in tornado

Tags: python, websocket, tornado, django-channels, sockjs-tornado

I am the beginner to tornado(python based web server). I have to create an application which will have public chat rooms and private messaging between two users.so, I have been looking for a good tutorial about tornado to implement the same but what i found is we can just create the websockets and once we have connected to socket we can send message to server and we can open multiple tabs of browser to replicate multiple users. So all users can send messages to server and every other user and can see all those messages but i need to create private message chat between two users like whatsapp. So can i do the same with tornado ? Please help me out. Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can form sockets, from client to the server then yes!
Sockets are just data streams.  You will have to add chat room request data and authentication to the sockets so the server can direct each client to the appropriate chat 'room' (or drop the connection if authentication fails).
after that it's the same as what you have implemented already.

For secure chat, you'll need some form of encryption on top of all this - at least so that clients know they are talking to the correct server.  From there it's adding encryption for clients to know they are talking to the right clients.

The final step would be to implement peer to peer capabilities after authenticating at the server.